# Getting error "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Base' before initialization" when running a next.js webapp locally

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsx

This is the full index.tsx file's contents:

```
import { Base } from '../templates/Base';

const Index = () => <Base />;

export default Index;
```

I've checked other posts with this error message, but none have been structured like this. I'm not really sure what's causing the error, as Base is imported before being referenced. What would "initialization" of Base look like in this instance?

[image]

The Base file:

```
import { Meta } from '../layout/Meta';
import { AppConfig } from '../utils/AppConfig';
import { Banner } from './Banner';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import { Hero } from './Hero';
import { List } from './List';
import { Navbar } from './Navbar';
import { VerticalFeatures } from './VerticalFeatures';
// import { Search } from './Search';

const Base = () => (
  <div className="antialiased text-gray-600">
    <Meta title={AppConfig.title} description={AppConfig.description} />
    <Navbar />
    <Hero />
    {/* <Search /> */}
    <List />
    <VerticalFeatures />
    <Banner />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

export { Base };
```

Comment: Can you also share `../templates/Base` file?

Comment: I suspect a case of circular references here. Is your AppConfig or Meta module importing index.tsx? You could use a tool like dependency-cruiser to discover circular imports.

Comment: +1 to @TamasHegedus. You could also use [eslint-plugin-import/no-cycle](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-cycle.md) to detect this problem in your IDE itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check for Circular Imports:

Ensure that there are no circular imports between your components. Circular imports can lead to this kind of error.
Make sure that you're not importing the Base component in a way that creates a circular reference.

Comment: you copy and pasted this from a generative AI, didn't you?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there has been a change in SWC： [https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46734；](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/46734%EF%BC%9B)

After changing const to function, there were no errors reported；

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Define `Base` component directly inside `index.tsx` component.

I believe that would work. Then you can start refactoring from there.

I had a similar issue. With mine, I had a `constants.ts` file and a `helpers.ts` file. I was importing a function from `helpers.ts` and using inside `constants.ts`. It was solved when I moved the function from `helpers.ts` and directly implemented within `constants.ts`